# Search query from multiple fields MySQL LIke 20-30

Tags: mysql

I want to add search functionality in my site for multiple column.
I have Product Table that have multi column. I want to add search according to all column
eg. brand, size, color, title, description etc sol please suggest me any query

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: i guess for now, google is your friend not Stackoverflow

Comment: [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is your best friend for SQL issues. You should begin with creating a working example of your data. Do not forget to save your project once it has been created, and linking your url to the SQLFiddle sample in your question.

Comment: Yes,
SELECT * FROM `product_meta` WHERE model LIKE '%aaa%' OR color LIKE '%aaaa%'

I used this query but when i apply 40 fields than query is very big so tell me small query solutions

Comment: actually you need to edit your question, like how can i use LIKE for if i have multiple columns, or best way to optimize etc

Comment: On my site I picked three or four major search fields and just did the individual sql queries on each.  I suppose your best solution is to do some kind of side submenu like Amazon where the user "filter down by" certain fields in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple columns than you can use like that:

```
$searchingFilters = array('model','color','brand','size'); // your columns array.
$searchingValue = "sports shoes"; // your searching input
foreach ($searchingFilters as $key => $columnname) {
    $likeArr[] = $columnname. " LIKE '%".$searchingValue."%'";
}
echo "SELECT * FROM product_meta WHERE (". implode(" OR ", $likeArr).")";
```

**Query Result is:**

```
SELECT * FROM product_meta WHERE (model LIKE '%sports shoes%' OR color LIKE '%sports shoes%' OR brand LIKE '%sports shoes%' OR size LIKE '%sports shoes%')
```

You can also get your columns name by using `MYSQL` Query.

Comment: If I use this method than 40 time run the loop and than make query.
the query response is delay. Is any alternate solution for this problem.
Or can I use this solution

Comment: no sir, If you have any idea please tell me

Thank you

Comment: well, you cant use any cache type thing here for foreach or for loop, two solution as i thinking, one is use AJAX, and second is create this loop in default when user visit on your page, and store in cookies as a string after implode, and check if cookie exist don't save againt... and use this cookie value in searching...